# Bluetooth libraries not correctly install with bluez 5.47 install

Tags: bluetooth

I installed Bluez version 5.47 onto a Pi-3 running Raspbian version 9 (Stretch).
files were copied into /home/pi/bluez-5.47 directory and successfully executed the dependencies, compile, make and install scripts.
The "bluetoothctl" tool seems to work correctly, however I am having difficulties programming the interface in c.  The include libraries were located and copied to eliminate the “bluetooth/bluetooth.h” not found error. I copied the bluetooth,h file from the bluez-5.47/android directory to the /usr/include/bluetooth directory.

Now when I compile with the following command

```
gcc simplescan.c -lbluetooth -o scan
```

I get the following error msg,

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbluetooth
```

A search for the bluetooth.so file finds it at the following location

```
/usr/lib/arm-lunux-gnueabohf/lxpanel/plugins
```

I copied the bluetooth.so file to the /usr/bin directory and still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question. As it turns out there are many tutorials on compiling and installing the bluez bluetooth package but they are out of date. By default the latest version of the bluez Makefile no longer installs the Bluetooth library.  To install the library you must invoke the `./configure` command with the `--enable-library` option as follows:

```
./configure –enable-library
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Did the trick for me with bluez 5.50. For completeness, one should search when this option has become available or disabled by default and add that to your answer. I would recommend accepting your own answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the Raspbian repositories aren't providing the features or a specific version you need, it's best to install via **apt**.

```
sudo apt install libbluetooth-dev
```

That `bluetooth.so` which you found is a plugin for LXPanel. It's not the same as `libbluetooth.so`.